# How can I call a java static method in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I wish to call class on the String class. How can I access this static method?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can call a static method using `(ClassName/methodName arguments)`.

However `class` is not a static method, it's a java keyword and you don't need it in clojure. To get the Class object associated with the String class, just use `String`.

Answer (score 24):

An example is worth 100 words:

```
(. String (valueOf 1))
```

Comment: If I have an instance of a class but not the class name itself, how can I call a static method? (. (class my-instance) staticMethod 10). I get an error "No matching method staticMethod found taking 1 args for class java.lang.Class", even though (class my-instance) does not return java.lang.Class.

Answer (score 7):

Your question has been answered, I think, but if you really do want to get the class of an unknown object, you can use the class function:

```
> (class "Foo")
java.lang.String
```

As in java, to specify classes outside of java.lang as literals, you need to either import them, or specify the full package + class name using dot (.) separators.

Answer (score 6):

Class doesn't have a "class" method, nor a "class" member. The symbol String is mapped to the class java.lang.String, if what you want to get is the equivalent of Java's `String.class`. If you want to call a static method of the String class, the syntax is `(String/methodName arg1 arg2)`.