# Clojure Java Interop - reference to field ... can't be resolved

Tags: java, clojure, interop, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

I am working on a clojure project where I want to create a class in Java and then instantiate that class and call a method from within my clojure code.

My Java code is located in resources/MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {

    public static long myMethod() {
        long i = 1; 
        return i;
    }

}
```

And in my clojure code I have

```
(import MyClass)
...
(def my-object (MyClass.))
(.myMethod my-object)
```

I compiled my class and ran lein compile, but when I run my code I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: myMethod for class MyClass
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:300)
```

What am I doing wrong?  It looks like the import statement worked, as the the instantiation, but Im not able to call the method.  Help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424520/how-can-i-call-a-java-static-method-in-clojure

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for not finding that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for static methods use a `/` instead of a `.`

```
(MyClass/myMethod)
```