# how to translate the double colon operator to clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I discovered a new syntax for java 8 reading through the [source](https://github.com/scireum/sirius-kernel/blob/master/src/main/java/sirius/kernel/Sirius.java) for a framework I'm attempting to wrangle:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(Sirius::stop));
```

In clojure, I can translate it as:

```
(.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. ????))
```

But I'm not sure what to put for the `???`

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a java static method in clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424520/how-can-i-call-a-java-static-method-in-clojure)

Comment: are you serious? I took a look at the answers and they DO NOT answer what I need to put in the `???`

Comment: "double colon" = static method.

Comment: I get that.. `Sirius/stop` does not work in clojure.

Comment: `(Thread. #(Sirius/stop))` should work, it is just a static method.

Comment: The difference here being that it seems like `::` is smart enough to know Thread needs a runnable? I'm not sure how the original worked, but making a lambda gives you a runnable, which is a valid constructor arg for `Thread`.

Comment: @Havenard the double colon does not mean static method. It is a Java 8 method handle (in this case to a static method). A method handle (similar to a function pointer) means that you can provide a method that is invoked at a later time (in this example when `Thread.start()` is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IFn extends Runnable, so you can just do

```
#(Sirius/stop)
```

It is worth noting that

- You have to make the lambda. Clojure won't let you refer to it just as `Sirius/stop`
- Java 8 functional interfaces under the hood work by making anonymous implementations of interfaces with only one method. So

  new Thread(Sirius::stop)

is just syntactic sugar for

```
new Thread(new Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Sirius.stop();
    }
})
```

If the interface in question isn't Runnable/Callable, you'll have to use the reify macro.

Comment: @zcaudate can you up vote/ mark as correct then please

Answer (score 2):

@george-simms has the correct explanation, but for anyone who is looking for an example which is not a `Runnable`/`Callable`, and need to use `reify`, here it is.

Say you want to use the `DateTimeFormatter` `parse` method like this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE();
LocalDate d = dtf.parse("2019-04-04", LocalDate::from);
```

You need to check the Functional interface type of the second param of `parse`, which is `TemporalQuery` in our case. That means, you need to `reify` `TemporalQuery`, and implement its only method (Functional interfaces always have only one method), so that it calls the static method `from` on the `LocalDate` class. So in Clojure it would translate too:

```clj
(import 'java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)
(import 'java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery)
(import 'java.time.LocalDate)

(let [dtf (DateTimeFormatter/ISO_LOCAL_DATE)]
  (.parse dtf "2019-04-04"
          (reify TemporalQuery
                 (queryFrom [this temporal]
                            (LocalDate/from temporal)))))
```