# Calling java in clojure

Tags: java, clojure

If i want to call java methodes or fields in clojure i can use the dot special form, since clojure strings are implemented as java strings i think i should be able to call the String methodes of java by something like (.toUpperCase "clojure") which works. My question is why can i not access to all of the java Methods in the same manner? For example `(.valueOf 3)` which is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) static method gives me an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a java static method in clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424520/how-can-i-call-a-java-static-method-in-clojure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is's a `static` method, so also in java you would call `String.valueOf(3)`:

```
user=> (String/valueOf 3)
"3"
```